# How can I know how many people have their own page on Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

I want to know how many people *have been famous* (=have their own Wikipedia page) since the beginning of time.

Is there a way I can see all the articles of the same category? Maybe querying the entire Wikipedia by the category *real person*?

Or is there a better way to get this info than Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

You can check both [Category:Living people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Living_people) and [Category:Dead people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Dead_people) for a full list of people that are on Wikipedia. These two categories represent pages that are about actual people (who are likely to be famous due to their notability policy).

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to mine it from the Wikidata project. The Wikidata project is a machine-readable Wikipedia database. Unfortunately, to extract this data, you need to know the RDA model and SPARQL language. Here is the link to submit questions: [query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org/)

However, I will state that Wikipedia does not contain all famous personalities. Wikipedia may also contain unknown personalities because no one has yet had time to challenge their importance. And above all, Wikipedia does not judge meaning by social significance, but by bibliographic significance. That is for Wikipedia, an important person is not, for example, one who has a lot of fans, but one who is mentioned in unbiased independent non-trivial literature. It can happen that some musicians or Influencers who are known by thousands of people are socially significant, but do not have a password on Wikipedia.